# JSON griddata source

Tags: shieldui

I am trying the trial MVC version. Couple of questions:

- Does it support MVC5
- I did the download per instruction but then when I looked at the grid example, I saw this:

Where is this file is supposed to be located?   I don't have it in my content file!!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ShieldUI components support mvc 5. 
You can get the trial version from the "download" section, once you log into the system.

While getting started, you can review the MVC tab on each demo, and review the underlying code. Here is an example:
https://demos.shieldui.com/mvc/area-chart/axis-marker

Cheers